# Sqlite db in android on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

My android app is creating and using a sqlite db and I wanted to know if the db is the same in evry device that runs the app?
I mean , if someone inserted somthing to the db by using my app , does it apply to all other devices? or does it create the db in evry device and thus it apply changes only in that particular device..?
I forgot to mention that I am not using a server

Comment: No, each device has a separate db. It's just a **local** db

Answer (score 1):

Just for that device, if you want to update every users device you will need to build some communication with your server.

Comment: Thought so... how do I create a server?

Comment: Ouch... I don't think this is a simple question, first you need to understand what you have (server)? What language do you wan't to work and a lot of other things...

Comment: I have a simple computer, windows 7, eclipse and an android app that needs a server . English is fine with me.